# Alexa lambda JS how to access array data from external .js file

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

i'm building an alexa skill in lambda with JS code.
i have **2 files**. one with regular code for alexa skill to work, and second file has an array with data that i will be needing when triggering an Inttent.

¿what code do i have to use in order to allow alexa read the array data from the second file?

file 1

```
let CountryInfoSlot = resolveCanonical(this.event.request.intent.slots.CountryInfo);

console.log (CountryInfoSlot);

CountryInfoSlot = CountryInfoSlot.toLowerCase();

if (CountryInfoSlot == 'France'){

var FranceInfo = require ('/FranceInfo.js');

var N = FranceInfo.length;

var index = Math.round(Math.random()*(N-1));

var answer = FranceInfo[index];

this.response.speak(answer);

this.emit(':responseReady);

}
```

file 2

```
var FranceInfo = [

'The language spoken in France is french',

'Paris is the capital of France',

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your info file to export the data. Change your file 2 to export the variable you want to access like this:

```
var FranceInfo = [

'The language spoken in France is french',

'Paris is the capital of France',

];

module.exports.data = FranceInfo;
```

And then you can require that variable in your first file like so:

```
const FranceInfoData = require('./FranceInfo');

var FranceInfo = FranceInfoData.data;
```

Then your FranceInfo variable would be equal to the array in the external file.

This isn't the only way to do this, but it is one of the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You could either read using `fs` and store the values as an array in the second file and parsed in the first.

OR

since you are using `require` in the first file, use `module.exports = FranceInfo` at the end of the second file so that it can be loaded into the first

Comment: hi. thanks for your answer. I dont know how module.exports works. I tried to follow your instructions, but did not work. could you give me an example please? thanks again